# Multiplier Algebra: Double Centralizer?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $A$.

Consider operators:
$$(L,R)\in\mathcal{B}(A):\quad L(a)b=aR(b)$$

Does that imply:
$$L(ab)=L(a)b\quad R(ab)=aR(b)$$

How to check this?

*Reference: [Lawrence G. Brown, Stable isomorphism of hereditary subalgebras of a $C^*$-algebra.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102811431)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $c\in A$, $$ L(ab)c=abR(c)=aL(b)c.$$ As this holds for any $c\in A$, it follows that $L(ab)=aL(b)$. Similarly, 
$$
cR(ab)=L(c)ab=cR(a)b,
$$
so $R(ab)=R(a)b$.

Comment: The usual notation is to have $aL(b)=R(a)b$ right? Does the condition $ac=0\forall c\in A$ implying $a=0$ have a name?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. As for the condition, I don't think it has a name; it follows easily from the fact that any C$^*$-algebra has an approximate identity.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: If $ac=0$ for all $c\in A$, then $aa^*=0$ for $c=a^*$. But  $aa^*=0$ iff $a=0$.

Comment: True, that's way way easier. When I wrote the comment I had "C$^*$-identity" in the back of my mind, but somehow I thought first about approximate identities.